# PHP XML reader by tags

Tags: php, xml

I have this XML file name update.xml linked in the pastebin below

https://pastebin.com/kFjX5Wka

Now I would like to make the output like:

```
Manufacturer Google:

Device codename: angler
Download: download tag link here from <angler>

Device codename: bullhead
Download: download tag link here from <bullhead>

Manufacturer OnePlus:

Device codename: cheeseburger
Download: download tag link here from <cheeseburger>

Device codename: dumpling
Download: download tag link here from <dumpling>
```

What I have so far

```
if (file_exists('update.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('update.xml');
    foreach($xml as $manufacturer){
        echo $manufacturer['id'] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    exit('Failed to open update.xml.');
}
```

This returns the manufacturers, but am blocked at parsing the info from them
So can someone point me to the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go further and examine `children` of each `manufacturer`:

```
if (file_exists('update.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('update.xml');
    foreach($xml as $manufacturer){
        echo $manufacturer['id'] . PHP_EOL;
        foreach ($manufacturer as $k => $v) {
            // `$k` gives you a tagname, 
            // `$v->download` gives value of `download` tag
            echo $k . $v->download . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
} else {
    exit('Failed to open update.xml.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will works!

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);
foreach ($xml->manufacturer as $manufacturer){
    echo "Manufacturer {$manufacturer['id']}:<br><br>";
    foreach ($manufacturer as $codename => $v){
        echo "Device codename: {$codename}<br>";
        echo "Download: {$v->download}<br>";
    }
    echo "<hr>";
}
```